# MYSQL master-master replication

Tags: mysql, replication

When i restart any server from working master-master replication it stops working , what problems likely ? Do i need to set binlog-do-db variable on both servers ? Do i need to set replicate-db variable ?

"show master status " output:

on server 1:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |      107 | purpledocsdbv1      |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

on server 2:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| bin-log.000001 |      78 |       |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You probably need to do a bit more research here and edit the question. As it is, it is unlikely to generate good quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

> When I restart any server from working master-master replication it stops working, what problems likely?

The problem that is listed in the `Last_Error` column when you execute `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`.

> Do i need to set binlog-do-db variable on both servers?

No.

> Do i need to set replicate-db variable?

No.